# How to customize the Visual Studio 2010 RC StartPage recent projects

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2010, start-page

I'd like to play around with customizing the visual studio 2010 rc start page recent items.  For what I have in mind I'd need to customize the datasource / databinding but I can't find where the information is coming from.

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    Style="{DynamicResource StartPage.ScrollViewerStyle}" 
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <sp:MruListBox 
        DataContext="{Binding Path=RecentProjects}" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"
        Background="Transparent"
        BorderThickness="0"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="MruList"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I see that it is binding to RecentProjects but where is that coming from?

Comment: Did you ever find a description of the properties that each recent project source item contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any real documentation about this. I guess you knew about [VS Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663382(VS.100).aspx), but it doesn't even scratch the surface.

Since there is a RecentProjects property used in a binding, there should be a type exposing such a property (or an implementation of ICustomTypeDescriptor, see [MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163816.aspx)). There is also a binding on the TeamFoundationClientSupported "property".

I found a property called TeamFoundationClientSupported in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal, in a class called Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.StartPageDataSource, but it is private, so cannot be used as is in a binding.
The constructor of this class contains quite a few lines like this:

```
base.AddBuiltInProperty(StartPageDataSourceSchema.CustomizationEnabledName, GetUserSetting(StartPageDataSourceSchema.CustomizationEnabledName, false));
    ...
base.AddBuiltInProperty(StartPageDataSourceSchema.TeamFoundationClientSupportedName, this.TeamFoundationClientSupported);
    ...
base.AddBuiltInProperty(StartPageDataSourceSchema.RecentProjectsDataSourceName, source3);
    ...
```

The last 2 are interesting: they "add a built-in property" called TeamFoundationClientSupported and RecentProjects...

Looking at the implementation at this method shows a simple dictionary with a key based on  the property name (the first parameter) and the value being the second parameter. This dictionary is used by a method called EnumProperties in              Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.UIDataSource. Going through the chain of uses, we arrive at a class called Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.DataSource (in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0), which implements ICustomTypeDescriptor. Thus, it explains how the properties are found by the binding system. I have not found how the DataSource type descriptor is linked to the StartPageDataSource class, but at least we can know the list of supported properties in the StartPageDataSource constructor.

Comment: Thanks John.  I suppose this is about as good as it's gonna get for right now.  Really I just wanted to extend the start page recent items to have the ability to rename the items (particularly the solutions).  This would be useful for anyone who works in a mainline scm.  At least I know I would get a ton of use out of it:)

Comment: I'm understand what the solution above is talking about, but I still don't understand how I can get a list of the properties that are available on the RecentProjectDataSource.  Is there any way to access this is code?

Comment: I have not read them, but maybe these articles will help: http://www.7388.info/index.php/article/wpf/2011-06-17/18130.html and http://www.7388.info/index.php/article/wpf/2011-06-15/18024.html

Comment: The two links in the last comment are currently showing Chinese or some other Asian language pages. I think they are "404" error pages.

Comment: @RenniePet: thank you for pointing this out. I can't remember how I managed to insert bad links. What I meant were these 2 articles: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/07/29/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-start-page-part-1.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/07/29/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-start-page-part-2.aspx Sorry about that.